# Getting Undefined for some values in console when sending the data using POSTMAN

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, postman

I am using postman to send data and on doing console.log , I am getting all the values expect the state, city and street. These 3 values are coming undefined . I am not sure if the nesting is even right and the way to assigning is correct or not. Please Help.

```
router.post("/signup", async(req, res) => {

    const { name, email, password, mobileno, state, city, street } = req.body;
    console.log(name, email, password, mobileno, state, city, street );
    if (!name || !email || !password || !mobileno || !state || !city || !street) {
        return res.status(422).json({ error: "please fill it again" });
    }

    try {
        const userExist = await User.findOne({ email: email });

        if (userExist) {
            return res.status(422).json({ error: "User already exits" });
        } else {

            const user = new User({
                name: name,
                email: email,
                password: password,
                address:[{
                    state: state,
                    city:city,
                    street:street,
                }],
                mobilenumber:mobileno
            });

            const userRegister = await user.save();

            if (userRegister) {
                res.status(201).send("data is inserted");
            }
        }
    }
    catch (error) {
        res.status(500).send("there is an error");
        console.log(error);
    }
});
```

Schema for address.

```
address: [
        {
          state: String,
          city:String,
          street:String   
        },
      ],
```

Comment: So the schema for address is an array of objects. Is that the intended behavior? If not you can send 
{ address: {state:String,city:String,street:String}} from postman. And when you do console.log. Try doing address.state, address.city, address.street.

Comment: @YashDigantJoshi Yes,I intend to do that. I want to store multiple addresses for single user and the address schema which I have mentioned above is a part of user schema , which has different fields.

Comment: Got it. In that case. Postman might be sending the address as an object. If you loop through the address object you'll be able to extract the fields from it. You get undefined because req.body doesn't have state, city, and street. It has address as an array that you can use to do business logic on.

Comment: @YashDigantJoshi What do you mean by loop through ?

Comment: The first line of router.post(). Add this:
`var {address} = req.body`
`console.log("Address", address)`

You will see your state, city, and street there. From there you can loop through the address array and extract the data.

Comment: @YashDigantJoshi I got the seperate data .The changes I made const { name, email, password, mobileno} = req.body;
    console.log(name, email, password, mobileno, address[0].state, address[0].city, address[0].street ); but the address data is not being saved in database.